# Magento admin controllers are awfully slow for AJAX

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to build a Magento admin extension for easier attribute manipulation which uses a lot of AJAX, but extending Magento admin controller's class(Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action) results in extremely slow AJAX response times(over 1 second, even for a blank page).
On the other hand, using the frontend controller class(Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action) speeds up things dramatically, but the extension must be accessible only in the admin panel.
I've read about solutions that allow you to read the admin session from a frontend controller and check if you're logged in as an admin, but they're very hackish and platform/settings dependent.
Have any of you guys run into this problem before?
Thanks in advance!